# resources for reviewing legal cases in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-research

Is there a (free) resource in the UK for someone to obtain details of various cases brought to court, for example details of case history, court rulings?

I have come across, for example, https://www.lexisnexis.com/uk/ but this appears restricted to legal students or professionals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main free resource is [Bailii](https://www.bailii.org/). I've sometimes also found cases on [Casemine](https://www.casemine.com/), which is free. The most popular paid resources are [Lexis](https://www.lexisnexis.co.uk/) and [Westlaw](https://uk.westlaw.com/).

In general, the paid databases are more complete and provide additional useful features such as cross-referencing statutes and cited/citing cases, information on whether the case is still good law or not, and others. For this luxury you will pay a heavy price: typically a few thousand a year depending on what type of subscription you take out. If you are lucky you can get free access via a university course.

With that said, Bailii can sometimes have judgments not found on the others; particularly unreported judgments. Ideally as a professional you would have access to all three if you can afford to do so.

If you want a specific case and can't find it on any database you may be able to [ask the court to provide a transcript](https://www.gov.uk/apply-transcript-court-tribunal-hearing), usually for a fee.